# AVFoundation: How can you get the video dimensions of a video being streamed by AVURLAsset?

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, dimensions, avurlasset

I need to know if the video I am playing from the web through AVURLAsset is portrait or landscape.

In the past I have done this with local videos by getting the video track's natural size, applying its preferred transform, and then comparing width and height. Example:

```
if let assetTrack = asset.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaType.video).first {
    let temp = assetTrack.naturalSize.applying(assetTrack.preferredTransform)
    let size = CGSize(width:fabs(temp.width), height: fabs(temp.height))
    return size.height > size.width
}
```

But for this streamed video, `asset.tracks` is empty, so I can't check the natural size.

Does anyone know how to resolve this?

Comment: Try `[asset tracksWithMediaCharacteristic:AVMediaCharacteristicVisual]]` and get its natural size? Are all tracks empty? Never ever had that before..

Comment: Unfortunately no luck with `tracksWithMediaCharacteristic` because yeah, the whole tracks array is empty. Thanks for the suggestion though!

Answer (score 1):

After playing around with it all day, I was able to find the solution:

Apparently streaming a .m3u8 HLS file will always result in an empty `asset.tracks` array.

The way to get the dimensions is through the `AVPlayerItem.presentationSize` property.